# How to convert to polar form?

Tags: circuit-analysis, thevenin

I'm still stuck on this task:

[image]

And I'm trying to calculate Vth. I've calculated:

[image]

And the Vth equation is: 
[image]

My problem now is that I want to convert from rectangular form to polar form for 100j/100 + 100j. I can't seem to get it right. I tried multiplying with the conjugate, however I just got (j). I want to convert it to polar form so that I can multiply the amplitudes and add the angles. However I'm stuck.

Could someone help?

**Update**: **I solved the upper part. Now I need help with time-domain. Please look below:**

I've got a hard time understanding how to calculate the time domain. I've found the Vth and Zth like so:

[image]

**Note:** Ignore the white markings, it was written in swedish, therefore I tried to hide it so it wouldn't led to confusion.

And this is how far I've gotten to be able to find the time domain: 
[image]

I don't know how to find the angle and how to proceed with finding the time domain so that I can draw a schematic of it.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you do multiply with the conjugate so show your working for this so we can see where your math went wrong. You should get 0.5 - j0.5 for the transfer function BTW.

Comment: @Andyaka Hi, I missed that j^2 = -1. So that's why I only got (j) in the end. I got it to be 0.5j+05 in the end.

Comment: @Andyaka I made changes to the post instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arctan function to find the angle, given the imaginary and real parts.